# How well would MvvmCross and CSLA.net work together in a multi-platform strategy (ASP.NET MVC, WP, WPF, WinRT, Win8, Android, iOS)

Tags: xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, csla

Long time lurker, first time questioner here :)

I have been looking into our company's next software system architecture. We have been using CSLA.net, to some extent, as our business object framework and are thinking of building our new architecture around it. CSLA.net has support for the platforms mentioned in the title and we are looking for mvvm framework that would work well with it.

At the moment we only support windows environments but are also looking to support at least Android and iOS (also mono in general is under consideration). We are looking to share as much of the code as possible between the platforms and MvvmCross seems like really nice piece of mvvm (+) framework, especially in that context. I have watched few n+1 videos and what I have seen so far has been very impressive. I also like the Stuart's style of introducing the framework and concepts around it.

Has anyone tried to build a cross platform application that uses both of these frameworks (CSLA.net and MvvmCross)? If yes, what have been your experiences like? Also if Stuart could comment on the issue of how to merg the viewmodels of the two frameworks. I remember Rocky (Rockford Lhotka) recommending, as a general tip when working with mvvm frameworks, to inherit CSLA.net viewmodelbase(not viewmodel) and implement also mvvm framework's requirements into that class. You can find source of the viewmodelbase from https://github.com/MarimerLLC/csla/blob/master/Source/Csla.Xaml/ViewModelBase.cs.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Harri

ps. I think, that this would make a great n+ video. Wouldn't it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've personally never used CSLA, but I have talked with it's original author, Rocky, both by email and in person.

CSLA presents itself as a business model object layer and that it can very successfully interoperate with independent Mvvm frameworks - see [Rocky's post on CSLA+Mvvm](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/faq/Mvvm.ashx)

MvvmCross provides the more application and UI level support - and leaves application authors free to choose how they write their business services and models.

Because of this, **yes** I think it should be possible and even straight-forward to use both of the frameworks together if you want to. To get started, it might be useful to write some prototypes - and perhaps to look at the way other integration has been done - e.g. [CSLA+Caliburn integration](http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/t/10178.aspx)

> ps. I think, that this would make a great n+ video.

I'd much rather see this type of article from someone who understands and uses CSLA. I would encourage all members of the MvvmCross community to contribute their own blog posts, articles, videos and github samples.

---

One caveat to this advice: I don't know if CSLA support Portable Class Libraries - if it doesn't then you'll probably need to use file-linking rather than PCLs in your app

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a multitude of MVVM frameworks; I've used CaliburnMicro and our own custom MVVM with success. If you haven't checked out Rocky's eBook series, you should definitely do so. One of the big gotchas is the limitations on reflection in Silverlight, hence also in WP8 and WinRT, so some reading up on that is well-advised.

Regarding Portable Class Libraries, you can't those for CSLA business objects (they require more stuff than is available in PCLs), so you do have to do the project linking. Typically, write the complete class in the .NET libary w/ pre-compiler directives, such as

```
#if !SILVERLIGHT
```

around code that can't be complied for Silverlight/WP8. I do use PCLs for some basic stuff, like enums and constants, but not for the business classes.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin have just released some updates that mean the latest framework 4.5 with async features can shortly be implemented...